# How Do I place Icon on the right

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I want to place the icon on the right. I used the alignment property but that did not have any effect

Here is the code:

```html
   Row(
    children:[
     InkWell(
        child: Icon(Icons.info, color:AppColor.darkBlue,),
        onTap: ()=>showDialog(context: context, builder: (context)=> alert),),
        Text(
          widget.heading,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: AppColor.primarypurple,
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
        ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mainAxisAlignment of the row

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children:[
     
        Text(
          widget.heading,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: AppColor.primarypurple,
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
        InkWell(
        child: Icon(Icons.info, color:AppColor.darkBlue,),
        onTap: ()=>showDialog(context: context, builder: (context)=> alert),),
        ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply interchange the items:-

```
Row(
    children:[
        Text(
          widget.heading,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: AppColor.primarypurple,
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
InkWell(
        child: Icon(Icons.info, color:AppColor.darkBlue,),
        onTap: ()=>showDialog(context: context, builder: (context)=> alert),),
        ],
        ),
```